# Orchard CMS: How to include model in the theme

Tags: orchardcms

I would like to include a Model in the theme, but I get the compilation error. How can I include it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To include cs files in your theme it needs to be it's own project. You can create it using this command in the orchard command line

codegen theme MyTheme /BasedOn:TheThemeMachine /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true